# PHP: Return a value from a Function and change the variable for the while Loop that it is in

Tags: php, function, while-loop

Is it possible to **execute a function**, then **return a new value for Var** and therefore **when it tries to loop again it checks the condition and detects the changes**?

---

Let's say I have this `function`:

```
   function changeZ(){
   $z=1
   return $z;      
   }
```

and this is my `while` loop:

```
$a = 0;
$z = 10;
while($a<$z){
changeZ();
$a++;
}
```

How should I modify the codes such that

the function `changeZ()` returns a new value for the variable `$z`

and therefore when the loop **checks for condition** (1<1), it returns a **false** and **stop looping**.

Comment: Generally speaking, `$z = changeZ()` -- but this doesn't make sense the way the code is written. What are you trying to do here? You are walking down the wrong path.

Comment: @Jon I have a function that interacts with database. The while loop loops depends on a result I get after interacting with the database.

Comment: That doesn't really say anything...

Comment: @Jon I am just not so sure if `$z = changeZ();` is suitable in this situation as `$z` isn't the main subject in this function. `$z` only changes under a condition, let's say, if a row has a particular value in a table.

Comment: Yeah, so pass the whole row to the function. That's what I mean that you are going down the wrong path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass by reference or return the value

```
$z = 100;
change($z);

function change(&$var) {
  $var = 1;
}

$z = 100;
$z = change($z);
function change($var) {
  return $var * 100 - 50;// Logic with $z obviously can be whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The $z in your function and the $z you use in the loop are not the same guys. So you have to set the value of the loop-z to the return value of your function...

```
$a = 0;
$z = 10;

while($a<$z){
    $z = changeZ();
    $a++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put this

```
$a = 0;
$z = 10;
while($a<$z) {
    $z = changeZ();
    $a++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$z = changeZ();
```

but as commented, you appear to definitely going about this wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = 0;
$z = 10;
while($a<$z){
$z = changeZ();
$a++;
}
```

Since your function returns a value you should set your variable to contain the returned value. This will do what you asked resulting in the loop running only once.

Another thing you can do is pass the variable into a function like so

```
function changeZ($in){
$out = $in-1;
return $out;
}

$a = 0;
$z = 10;
while($a<$z){
$z = changeZ($z);
$a++;
}
```

This will result in the loop running 5 times as one number goes up the other goes down
    0<10
    1<9
    2<8
    3<7
    4<6

Answer (score 0):

you can use this for your purpose for storing the returned data from function into an array.

```
function changeZ(){
     $z = $row['result'];       //your data from database
     return $z;      
}

$a = 0;
$z = 10;
$returned_value=new array();

while($a<$z){
    $returned_value[] = changeZ();
    $a++;
}
```